# How to unzip files after an install using Advanced Installer

Tags: installation, windows-installer, unzip, advanced-installer

I have a huge zipped folder with wav files in it (o.5 GB zipped), that needs to be unzipped after installation.  I'm using Advanced Installer.  I was hoping there would be some custom action that would unzip the files for me after the install is complete, but no such luck.  A quick search for using command line to unzip files, also didn't yield much results, other than powershell scripts.

What's the best way to unzip files after an install using Advanced Installer (deploying on a Windows7/10 machine)?

Comment: Have you checked out this thread?: http://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=30632

Comment: @BogdanMitrache No.  I'll take a look at it, thanks.  Looks like 7zip may be the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up just unzipping the files and adding them in unzipped form to the Advanced Installer.  Their built in compression is pretty good.  The only issue is that the MSI build takes 7 minutes now, but I can live with that.

Comment: how did you add them? i have to add the mall manually an this is taking way to long...

Comment: @Silve2611 Don't remember, but I'm pretty sure I just dragged them into the target folder in their visual IDE.

Comment: I have 2GB of files to add, and it absolutely destroys the Organization page having so many files. I'm going to continue my search for unzipping them.

Comment: @JayCroghan What about using a Powershell script that runs after the install, and unzips the files?

Comment: @Eternal21 that worked like a charm thank you. I added the zip as a file to the installer and then as a post install script I run a power shell command that extracts the zip.